# Spring Batch 5 - Autowiring Feign Client bean not found

Tags: kotlin, spring-batch, feign

I have a Spring Batch application which has a processor which fetches metadata from an API with Openfeign. The FetchMetaDataProcessor autowires the MoviesRemote class but states "Could not autowire. No beans of 'MoviesRemote' type found.".

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = ["be.robbevw.fliximportmoviesjob.remotes"])
class FlixImportMoviesJobApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<FlixImportMoviesJobApplication>(*args)
}
```

```
@FeignClient(name = "movies", url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3")
interface MoviesRemote {

    @RequestMapping("/movie/{movieId}?append_to_response=videos%2Cwatch%2Fproviders&api_key=cd999edfe5283dd7798a09f49f851c0c&language=en-US&page={page}")
    fun getMovieMetaData(@PathVariable movieId: Int): JsonNode

}
```

```
@Component
class FetchMetaDataProcessor : ItemProcessor<MovieDto, MovieDto> {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var moviesRemote: MoviesRemote

    override fun process(item: MovieDto): MovieDto? {
        val movieMetaData = moviesRemote.getMovieMetaData(item.id)

        // TODO: Set the metadata on the item

        return item
    }
}
```

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.20"
//    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.20"
}

group = "be.robbevw"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2023.0.0"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21")
//    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.16.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have already tried to add the @Component annotation to the reader.

I have added the @EnableFeignClients annotation and added the base package as well.

Comment: Are you sure there is a bean of type `MoviesRemote` defined in the application context? Is `MoviesRemote` defined in a package scanned by Spring Boot?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine

The remote is defined in package "be.robbevw.fliximportmoviesjob.remotes". The annotation in the application start point is '@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = ["be.robbevw.fliximportmoviesjob.remotes"])' which is the same package.

It should work like this in a default Spring Boot app. But it does not autowire with Spring Batch.

Comment: Make sure the item processor class is also in a scanned package so it is defined as a bean for the dependency injection to work. There is nothing specific to Spring Batch for dependency injection not to work if batch components (reader, processor, writer, etc) are defined as spring beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was initializing the FetchMetaDataProcessor in my StepBuilder factory manually by creating the object manually.

The solution was to let Spring autowire this processor in the batch config file. IntelliJ stills throws an error, but the application works now.